# Return value of text input on Enter (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'd like to pass the value of a text input into a switch statement when the user presses the enter button. I'd like to do this without using a button to submit. I have a short list of commands the user can enter into the text field, and the result of the switch statement simply logs to the console for now.

EDIT: I should also mention that I'm trying to build this using pure JS.

```
var cmdValue = document.getElementById('cmdLine').value;

switch(cmdValue){
    case "jump":
        console.log("FTL Jump to new system: SUCCESS");
        break;
    case "refuel":
        console.log("Refuel: SUCCESS");
        break;
    case "repair":
        console.log("Repair: SUCCESS");
    default:
        console.log("Command not recognized");
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pU97T/1/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to register a callback function, which will be invoked whenever a key in keyboard is pressed and your logic has to be in that function (or some other function and invoked from this callback function), like this

```
document.getElementById("cmdLine").addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var cmdValue = document.getElementById('cmdLine').value;

        switch (cmdValue) {
            case "jump":
                console.log("FTL Jump to new system: SUCCESS");
                break;
            case "refuel":
            case "repair":
                console.log("Refuel: SUCCESS");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Command not recognized");
        }

    }
});
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/pU97T/2/)

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain how I can improve this post?

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery...

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        //whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pU97T/3/)

This is more or less what you want. You'll need to attach an event handler to the input and pass it a function containing your switch statement logic:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var cli = document.getElementById('cmdLine');

  // Add event listener on the 'keyup' event to execute the command
  cli.addEventListener('keyup', executeCommand);

  function executeCommand(e) {
    var cmdValue = cli.value;   // get the current value of the cli
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {     // if key equals 'enter'
      switch(cmdValue){
          case "jump":
              console.log("FTL Jump to new system: SUCCESS");
              break;
          case "refuel":
              console.log("Refuel: SUCCESS");
              break;
          case "repair":
              console.log("Repair: SUCCESS");
          default:
              console.log("Command not recognized");
      }
    }
  }
}
```